# QT writeDatagram function return -1 when I tried to send data to specific IP Address

Tags: qt, udp, udpclient, qudpsocket

I want to sending 8 byte data from PC(Linux) to another device.
PC(Linux) IP     : 10.100.40.99
Another Device IP: 10.100.40.62 Port: 7070

```
udpPacket_t udpPacket;
udpPacket.byte0 = 0x00;
udpPacket.byte1 = 0x00;
udpPacket.byte2 = 0x00;
udpPacket.byte3 = 0x00;
udpPacket.byte4 = 0x00;
udpPacket.byte5 = 0x00;
udpPacket.byte6 = 0x00;
udpPacket.byte7 = 0x00;

QByteArray data;
data.append(udpPacket.byte0);
data.append(udpPacket.byte1);
data.append(udpPacket.byte2);
data.append(udpPacket.byte3);
data.append(udpPacket.byte4);
data.append(udpPacket.byte5);
data.append(udpPacket.byte6);
data.append(udpPacket.byte7);

int ret = socket->writeDatagram(data, QHostAddress("10.100.40.62"), 7070);
```

writeDatagram function returns "-1". When I tried to send data to 10.100.40.255 IP Address. The data sends successfully. But when I tried to send data to specific IP Address instead of broadcast, writeDatagram returns -1. What am I missing ?

Comment: -1 means error. you can connect a slot to `errorOccured` signal of the socket or I guess you can read `socket->errorString()`.

Comment: Thanks for support. I was mistaken about my PC IP address. When I corrected IP address the communication is established.